# RegEx to match a text string excluding digits by specific rule

Tags: regex

I have some strings:

```
ALFA ROMEO 4C
BMW X7 BLACK
BMW X7 BLACK COLOUR
BMW X7
BMW
BMW X 7
BMW 7 SERIES
BMW 7SERIES
BMW 7S
BMW (X7)
```

I want to get:

```
ALFA ROMEO 4C
BMW X7 BLACK
BMW X7 BLACK COLOUR
BMW X7
BMW
BMW X
BMW
BMW 7SERIES
BMW 7S
BMW
```

1. If digits are not together with letters `[A-Z]` then pattern should grab before them.
2. If there is no letters `[^A-Z]` after letters `[A-Z]` and space then pattern should grab before them.

Comment: Where does `BMW 7SERIES` come from? I only see `BMW 7series`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, fixed, thx.

Comment: @anubhava, because there is the space betweeen "7" and "SERIES" (par. 1 in my question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a positive lookahead is supported, you could use start matching `[A-Z]` and repeat matching what is on the right 0+ times `[A-Z0-9]+` when it does not contain only digits.

```
^[A-Z]+(?: (?![0-9]+\b)[A-Z0-9]+)*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Z]+` Match 1+ times char A-Z
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `` (?![0-9]+\b)` `` Match space, assert what is directly on the right are not only digits
  - `[A-Z0-9]+` Match 1+ times chars A-Z or digits
- `)*`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/spQ28N/1)

There is no language listed, but for example using Javascript:

```js
const pattern = /^[A-Z]+(?: (?![0-9]+\b)[A-Z0-9]+)*/;
[
  "ALFA ROMEO 4C",
  "BMW X7 BLACK",
  "BMW X7 BLACK COLOUR",
  "BMW X7",
  "BMW",
  "BMW X 7",
  "BMW 7 SERIES",
  "BMW 7SERIES",
  "BMW 7S",
  "BMW (X7)"
].forEach(str => console.log(str.match(pattern)[0]));
```

Comment: Your pattern is very good, thanx, but how to make it work with not `[a-z]` symbols? I guess there is a problem with `\b`.

Comment: Perhaps you could try `^[^\d\s]+(?: (?![0-9]+\b)\S+)*`  https://regex101.com/r/8IojS1/1

Comment: I mean: https://regex101.com/r/8IojS1/3, it should grab last string. And if string looks like https://regex101.com/r/8IojS1/2, pattern should grab before "BMW", because it's not cyrillic word.

Comment: I use this version of your pattern: https://regex101.com/r/8IojS1/5.

Answer (score 1):

A bit convoluted but this could work:

```
^[A-Z ]+?(\d[A-Z]|[A-Z]\d).*|^[A-Z ]+
```

and your matches will be in `$0`

```
ALFA ROMEO 4C
BMW X7 BLACK
BMW X7 BLACK COLOUR
BMW X7
BMW
BMW X
BMW
BMW 7SERIES
BMW 7S
BMW
```

https://regex101.com/r/YZ9uuw/1